# Pandas extract only capturing first character

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to do an extract to capture all characters that match a regular expression and add those extracted characters to another column. When I run the code below, it only captures the first character. I want to capture all the letters, except W, and also no numbers or any dashes.

Here's the code:

```
df["type"] = df["callsign"].str.extract(r'([^W0-9-])')
```

Currently the data frame shows the below result.

| callsign | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1AB3-W9 | A |
| 23DC-W0 | D |

But I need it to produce:

| callsign | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1AB3-W9 | AB |
| 23DC-W0 | DC |

Comment: What is the logic you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to `extract` the letters right before the `-W`, use:

```
df["type"] = df["callsign"].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)-W')
```

For the first set of letters that are not `W`, you're missing a `+`:

```
df["callsign"].str.extract(r'([^W0-9-]+)')
```

Comment: Great, ok, I added the plus (+) to the code and it extracts the characters I need to the type column. 
`df["callsign"].str.extract(r'([^W0-9-]+)')`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `extract()`, use `replace()` to replace the unwanted characters with an empty string.

```
df["type"] = df["callsign"].str.replace(r'[W0-9-]', '')
```

Comment: Actually `replace` is less efficient than `extract`, so unless there is a good reason to use it it's most often better to try to `extract` directly ;)

Comment: But only if `extract()` does what you want. The capture group can only match a contiguous substring.

Comment: I agree, but this seems to be OP's case

Comment: It might be, I went by the text "I want to capture all the letters but no W and also no numbers or any dashes."

Comment: Fair enough, OP should clarify if a case such as `1AB3-W9CD0` is possible and what should be the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the other valid answers, you can use `findall`:

```
df["callsign"].str.findall(r'([^W0-9-])')
```

This will give you a list will all the matches, you can then join it:

```
df["type"] = df["callsign"].str.findall(r'([^W0-9-])').str.join("")
```